# Is my food-tracker's database designed properly? (ER diagram + SQL Relations)

Tags: database-design, sqlite, database-diagrams

My idea:

The database will store foods, days, and "inserted foods" aka diet_logs (days and diet_logs have both existence dependency)

for each diet_log of a specific day, I will create a relationship instance between a food instance and a day istance.

food quantity types may vary, eg: g, ml, ...

[image: ER Diagram]

[image]

ER conventions:

ovals = attributes (key attributes have their name underlined)

dotted ovals = derived attributes

diamond-shaped boxes = relationships

the participation constraint is specified by a single line for partial participation and by double lines for total participation (existence dependency)

Comment: Schema design is an [iterative process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+iterative+process) - you design, you code for it, you correct any mistakes (and there **will** be mistakes) - rinse and repeat!

Comment: @Vérace yeah I get your point, thanks

Comment: Yes, looks correct. Next time share a query that could import the schema so we can eventually edit it

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani Will do, thanks